# How to get absolute path of a file in a directory which is symbolic link?

Tags: c++, c

Now if there are two directories, `/code/build` is a symbolic link to `/build`.

```
l
/code/build -> /build
```

There is a binary file X in /build. When X is running, if I use `readlink("/proc/self/exe", path, 2048)`, the path is `/build/X`.

My question is how can I get the `/code/build/X` using c/c++?

Comment: Tag with either C or C++. Not both.

Comment: How would that work even just logically? There can be many symlinks to the same directory. So how can the code know which is the symlink that is wanted?

Comment: The question title doesn't match the question: in the title you're asking how to get the absolute file path from the symbolic link and in the question you're asking to get the symbolic link from the absolute path (which is an absurd requirement, see preceeding comment). Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

As Jabberwocky pointed out, your question is ambiguous.

If the question body applies -- "how to get from canonical path to (one of a multitude of possible) symlinked path", the comment by kaylum applies: It cannot be done, because which symlink out of a potential multitude would you like? (Aside from the effort finding all the possible symlinks being prohibitive.)

If the title applies -- "how to get from a (possibly symlinked) path to a canonical path (without symlinks), 4386427's comment applies -- C and C++ are different languages, please pick one.

---

For C++, [`std::filesystem::canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical):

```
auto path = std::filesystem::current_path();
std::cout << "Current path is: " << path << "\n"
             "Canonical path is: " << std::filesystem::canonical( path ) << "\n";
```

> Converts path p to a canonical absolute path, i.e. an absolute path
> that has no dot, dot-dot elements or symbolic links in its generic
> format representation. If p is not an absolute path, the function
> behaves as if it is first made absolute by
> std::filesystem::absolute(p). The path p must exist.

---

For C on POSIX, [`realpath()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html):

```
char path[ PATH_MAX ];
char canonical[ PATH_MAX ];

// error handling omitted for readability
readlink( "/proc/self/exe", path, PATH_MAX );
realpath( path, canonical );
printf( "Current path is: %s\n"
        "Canonical path is: %s\n",
        path, canonical );
```

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./,
> /../ and extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named by
> path to produce a canonicalized absolute pathname.